# Фрагмент фотографии // с фотографии

Tags: предлоги, стилистическая-сочетаемость

Вопрос грамотной подписи фрагмента фотографии:

1. Фрагмент фотографии, *дата*
2. С фото, *дата*

Как объяснить неблагозвучность второго варианта?

Answer (score 1):

Понятие фотография многозначно. Корректно будет назвать изображение (иллюстрацию) снимком или фото; увеличенную (выбранную) его область — частью, фрагментом, деталью.

В подписи даются атрибуты, имеющие отношение к его оригинальному виду, не детали.

*Городской рынок.* Фото 1933 г. (Фрагмент)

Answer (score 0):

Возможные причины:
1) В первом случае назван предмет (*фрагмент*), а во втором — нет.
2) *Взяли фрагмент **с фото**.* || Звучит сомнительно, разговорно. Предлог "с" означает "с поверхности". Например, с [поверхности] фото можно взять отпечатки пальцев. Но можно взять фрагмент фото (без предлога).